# A sequence $x_n$ has a cauchy subsequence iff it has a subsequence ${x_{n_k}}$ for which $d({x_{n_k}},{x_{n_{k+1}}})<2^{-k}$ for all k

Tags: real-analysis

Can't make anny progress with this proof, someone knows this one?

Comment: Maybe $<2^{-k}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\cdots<2^{-k}$?

Comment: Yes sorry a typo